# How Do I bind a Color to a SolidColorBrush in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, brush

Can you bind a SolidColorBrush to a color in code behind?  I want to be able to do this:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("FontColor");
binding.Source = this;
SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
brush.SetBinding(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, binding);
```

I know the brush is not a BindingExpressionBase, so it does not have a SetBinding() method.  But you can set a binding in xaml.  How do you do it in code behind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.SetBinding`:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(brush, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Works beautifully.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: You are binding directly to a property on a control, I dont think this is what OP is asking